# Dynamically change background color of a cell <td> based on the value in the cell

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to change the background color of the cell based on the value calculated by the helper method CalculateVariance.
(code is in the comment section below)
This code is changing background color of all the cells in the Percentage Variance column to green.

Comment: <td style=@(PercentageVariance >25 ? "Background-color : Yellow" : "Background-color : Green")>PercentageVariance = @Html.CalculateVariance(double R1, double R2)</td>

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is PercentageVariance , you need to assign it before the  
try this

```
    @{
        var PercentageVariance = @Html.CalculateVariance(R1, R2);
    }
    <td style="@(PercentageVariance >25 ? "Background-color : Yellow" : "Background-color : Green")">PercentageVariance = @PercentageVariance </td>
```